# Why does unbuffer -p mangle its input?

Tags: expect, buffer

```
$ seq 10 | unbuffer -p od -vtc
0000000   1  \n   2  \n   3  \n   4  \n   5  \n   6  \n   7  \n   8  \n
```

Where did `9` and `10` go?

```
$ printf '\r' | unbuffer -p od -An -w1 -vtc
  \n
```

Why was `\r` changed to `\n`?

```
$ : | unbuffer -p printf '\n' | od -An -w1 -vtc
  \r
  \n
$ unbuffer -p printf '\n' | od -An -w1 -vtc
  \r
      \n
```

WTF?

```
$ printf foo | unbuffer -p cat
$
```

Why no output (and a one second delay)?

```
$ printf '\1\2\3foo bar\n'  | unbuffer -p od -An -w1 -vtc
$
```

Why no output?

```
$ (printf '\23'; seq 10000) | unbuffer -p cat
```

Why does it hang with no output?

```
$ unbuffer -p sleep 10
```

Why can't I see what I type (and why is it discarded even though `sleep` didn't read it)?

Incidentally, also:

```
$ echo test | unbuffer -p grep foo && echo found foo
found foo
```

How come `grep` found `foo` but didn't print the lines that contain it?

```
$ unbuffer -p ls /x 2> /dev/null
ls: cannot access '/x': No such file or directory
```

Why didn't the error go to `/dev/null`?

See also [Unbuffer converting all characters to bell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/521212)

```
$ echo ${(l[10000][foo])} | unbuffer -p cat | wc -c
4095
```

That's with:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid
Release:        n/a
Codename:       trixie
$ uname -rsm
Linux 6.5.0-3-amd64 x86_64
$ expect -c 'puts "expect [package require Expect] tcl [info patchlevel]"'
expect 5.45.4 tcl 8.6.13
$ /proc/self/exe --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)
```

Same on Ubuntu 22.04 or on FreeBSD 12.4-RELEASE-p5 (except the `od` commands have to be adapted there, and I get 2321 (all BEL characters there) instead of 4095 above).

Comment: What platform and userland tools are you on?

Comment: @sehe, see edit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`unbuffer` is a tool to disable the buffering that some commands do when their output doesn't go to a terminal device.

When their output goes to a terminal device, commands assume there's an actual user actively looking at the output, so they send it as soon as it's available. Well, not exactly, they send it line-based, that is send completed lines as soon as they're ready to output.

When it doesn't go to a terminal device, like when stdout is a regular file or a pipe, as an optimisation, they send it in blocks. That means fewer `write()`s and in the case of a pipe means the reader at the other end doesn't need to be woken up as often which means fewer context switches.

However that means that in:

```
cmd | other-cmd
```

run in a terminal, where `other-cmd` is some sort of filtering/transforming command, `other-cmd`'s stdout is line-buffered, but `cmd`'s is full-buffered, which means the interactive user doesn't see that output of `cmd` (as transformed by `other-cmd`) as soon as it's available but delayed and in large batches.

```
unbuffer cmd | other-cmd
```

Helps because it restores a line-based buffering for `cmd` even though its stdout is going to a pipe.

To do that, it starts `cmd` in a pseudo-terminal and forwards what comes from that pseudo-terminal to the pipe. So `cmd` thinks it's talking to a user again and does line-buffering.

`unbuffer` is actually written in `expect`. It's [an example script in the `expect` source code](https://salsa.debian.org/tcltk-team/expect/-/blob/6aa98389162f60d23d6c0af7b061b7b9e784f5ec/example/unbuffer), often included in the `expect` package supplied by OSes.

`expect` is a tool used to perform automatic interactions with terminal applications using pseudo-terminals, so that `unbuffer` command is trivial to write in `expect`. Jokingly, the *BUGS* section of `unbuffer`'s man page has: *The man page is longer than the program.* And indeed, the *program* is just:

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- tcl -*-
# The next line is executed by /bin/sh, but not tcl \
exec tclsh8.6 "$0" ${1+"$@"}

package require Expect


# -*- tcl -*-
# Description: unbuffer stdout of a program
# Author: Don Libes, NIST

if {[string compare [lindex $argv 0] "-p"] == 0} {
    # pipeline
    set stty_init "-echo"
    eval [list spawn -noecho] [lrange $argv 1 end]
    close_on_eof -i $user_spawn_id 0
    interact {
        eof {
            # flush remaining output from child
            expect -timeout 1 -re .+
            return
        }
    }
} else {
    set stty_init "-opost"
    set timeout -1
    eval [list spawn -noecho] $argv
    expect
    exit [lindex [wait] 3]
}
```

As you can see and as confirmed by the man page, `unbuffer` also supports a `-p` option.

In `unbuffer cmd`, the pseudo-terminal is not only connected to cmd's stdout, it's also connected to its stdin and stderr (remember `expect` is a tool intended to interact with commands):

```
$ tty; unbuffer readlink /proc/self/fd/{0..2}
/dev/pts/14
/dev/pts/15
/dev/pts/15
/dev/pts/15
```

That explains why `unbuffer ls /x 2> /dev/null` didn't send the errors to `/dev/null`, stderr is merged with stdout.

Now, `unbuffer` doesn't read anything from its own stdin and doesn't send anything for the stdin of `cmd`.

That means `A | unbuffer cmd | B` won't work.

That's where the `-p` (for `p`ipe) option comes in. As seen in the code, with `-p`, `unbuffer` uses `interact` instead of `expect` as the active loop that processes the data coming from the different channels.

With the `expect` statement alone, `expect` (the program/TCL library) reads what comes from the pseudo-terminal (so what `cmd` writes on the slave side via its stdout or stderr for instance), and just sends it to its own stdout.

With `interact`, `expect` does that but also:

- sends what it reads from its own standard input to the pseudo terminal (so `cmd` can read it there)
- and also, if `unbuffer`'s stdin happens to be a terminal device, `interact` puts it in `raw` mode with local `echo` disabled.

That's good in that in `A | unbuffer -p cmd | B`, `A`'s output can be read as input by `cmd` but means a few things:

- `unbuffer` configures the internal pseudo-terminal with `set stty_init "-echo"`, but not in `raw` mode. In particular, `isig` (the handling of `^C` (`\3`) / `^Z` /  `^\`), `ixon` (flow control, `^Q`/`^S` (`\23`)) are not disabled. When the input is a terminal device (which is how `expect`'s `interact` is meant to be used, but not `unbuffer`), that's fine as the host one is put in `raw` mode so that just means that processing is moved from the host terminal to the embedded pseudo-terminal, except for the fact that `echo` is disabled in both so you can't see what you type. But when it's not a terminal device, that means that for instance any 0x3 byte (`^C`) in the input (as when processing the output of `printf '\3'`) triggers a SIGINT and terminates the command, any 0x19 byte (`printf '\23'`) stops the flow. `icrnl` being not disabled explains why `\r`'s are changed to `\n`'s.
- It doesn't do the `stty -opost` that it otherwise does without `-p`. That explains why the `\n`'s output by `cmd` are changed to `\r\n`. And when the input is a terminal device, the fact that it puts that one in `raw`, so with `opost` disabled explains the mangled terminal output when the newline characters output by `od` are not transformed to `\r\n`.
- the internal pseudo-terminal still has the line editor enabled, so nothing will be sent to `cmd` unless there's a `\r` or `\n` character coming from the input, which explains why `printf foo | unbuffer -p cat` prints nothing.

  And since that line editor has a limit on the size of the line is may edit ([4095 on my system (Linux)](/a/643783), [a fifth of the tty speed](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/128f63cedc14ae21b35f74e11e2fe1a5659c58e8/sys/kern/tty.c#L128)¹ on FreeBSD), you end up with the kind of problem at [Unbuffer converting all characters to bell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/521212): the same thing happens as when you try to enter an overlong line on the keyboard in a dumb application such as `cat`. On Linux, all characters after the 4094<sup>th</sup> one are ignored, but `\n` is accepted and submits the line; on FreeBSD, after 38400/5 characters are entered, any extra is refused (even `\n`) and cause a BEL to be sent to the terminal². Which explains why you get 2321 BELs there (10001 - 38400/5).
- EOF handling is clunky with pseudo-terminal devices. When EOF is seen on `unbuffer`'s stdin, it can't forward that information to `cmd`. So in `seq 10 | od -vtc`, after `seq` has terminated, `od` is still waiting for more input from the pseudo-terminal which will never come. Instead, at that point, everything is torn down and `od` is killed (the man page does mention that limitation).

For its own purpose, it would be much better if `unbuffer` put the embedded pseudo-tty in `raw -echo` mode and left the host terminal device (if any) alone. However `expect` doesn't really support that mode of operation, it's not been designed for that.

Now, if `unbuffer` is about unbuffering stdout, there's no reason why it should touch stdin and stderr.

We can actually work around it by doing:

```
unbuffer() {
  command unbuffer sh -c 4<&0 5>&2 '
    exec <&4 4<&- 2>&5 5>&- "$@"' sh "$@"
}
```

That uses `sh` to restore the original stdin and stderr (passed along by the calling shell via fds 4 and 5; not using fd 3 as `expect` happens to explicitly using that one internally).

Then:

```
$ echo test | unbuffer readlink /proc/self/fd/{0..2} 2> /dev/null | cat
pipe:[184479]
/dev/pts/16
/dev/null
```

Only stdout goes to the pseudo-terminal to be unbuffered.

And all the other problems go away:

```
$ unbuffer ls /x 2> /dev/null
$ printf '\r'  | unbuffer od -An -w1 -vtc
  \r
$ : | unbuffer printf '\n' | od -An -w1 -vtc
  \n
$ unbuffer printf '\n' | od -An -w1 -vtc
  \n
$ printf foo | unbuffer cat
foo
$ printf '\1\2\3foo bar\n' | unbuffer od -An -w1 -vtc
 001
 002
 003
   f
   o
   o

   b
   a
   r
  \n
$ (printf '\23'; seq 10000) | unbuffer cat -vte | head
^S1$
2$
3$
4$
5$
6$
7$
8$
9$
10$
$ unbuffer sleep 10
I see what I type
$ I see what I type
zsh: command not found: I
$ echo test | unbuffer grep foo || echo not found
not found
$ echo ${(l[10000][foo])} | unbuffer cat | wc -c
10001
```

Also installing `expect` (which requires a TCL interpreter) seems a bit overkill when all you need is to make stdout of `cmd` go through a pseudo-terminal.

`socat` can also do it:

```
$ echo test | socat -u system:'readlink /proc/self/fd/[0-2]; wc -c',pty,raw - 2> /dev/null | cat
pipe:[187759]
/dev/pts/17
/dev/null
5
```

(it logs failure exit status, but otherwise does not propagate the command's exit status though).

The `zsh` shell even has builtin support for pseudo-ttys, and an `unbuffer` function could be written with little effort there with:

```
zmodload zsh/zpty
zmodload zsh/zselect
unbuffer() {
  {
    return "$(
      exec 6>&1 >&5 5>&-
      # here fds go:
      #  0,3: orig stdin
      #    1: orig stdout
      #  2,4: orig stderr
      #    5: closed
      #    6: to return argument
      zpty -b unbuffer '
        stty raw
        exec <&3 3<&- 2>&4 4>&-
        # here fds go:
        #     0: orig stdin
        #     1: pseudo unbuffering tty
        #     2: orig stderr
        # 3,4,5: closed
        #     6: to return argument
        "$@" 6>&-
        echo "$?" >&6 
      '
      fd=$REPLY
      until
        zselect -r $fd
        zpty -r unbuffer
        (( $? == 2 ))
      do
        continue
      done
    )"
  } 3<&0 4>&2 5>&1
}
```

Beware all those end up running in a new terminal and except for the `socat` approach (unless you use the `ctty` and `setid` options) in a new session. So now if those "fixed" `unbuffer`s are started in a background in the host terminal session, the `cmd` there won't be stopped from reading from the host terminal. For instance `unbuffer cat&` will end up with a background job reading from your terminal, causing havoc.

---

<sup>¹ Capped to 65536. The *speed* for a pseudo-terminal is irrelevant, but there has to be one advertised and I find it's 38400 by default on the FreeBSD system I tested this on. As the speed is copied from that of the terminal controlling `expect`, one can do a `stty speed 115200` (the maximum value AFAICT) before calling `unbuffer` to enlarge that buffer. But you may find that you still don't get the full 10000 char large line. That's [explained in the driver code](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/128f63cedc14ae21b35f74e11e2fe1a5659c58e8/sys/kern/tty_ttydisc.c#L131). You'll find `unbuffer -p cat` returns only 4096 bytes because that's as much `cat` requested in its first `read()` call, and the tty driver returned as much from the input line *but discarded the rest*(!). If you replace with `unbuffer -p dd bs=65536`, you'll get the full line (well, up to 115200/5 bytes).</sup>

<sup>² you can avoid those BELs by replacing `set stty_init "-echo"` with `set stty_init "-echo -imaxbel"` in the `unbuffer` script, but that won't help you get the data.</sup>

Comment: Excellent Q&A.  That sounds like hard-won knowledge!

Comment: This is an exceptionally thorough answer. Hall of fame stuff!